# Setting wget --header= in bash doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am trying to set the header within `wget`. From the command line, when I run `wget -d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"' http://website.com -O index`, it works as expected.

However, once I change the header to a variable and try to run the following `wget` command it stops working:

```
header='-d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"'
wget "$header" http://google.com -O index
```

...with error:

```
wget: invalid option -- ' '
wget: invalid option -- '-'
wget: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...
```

Comment: Try swapping your use of single and double quotes around the variable definition.  Double quotes can be interpreted, single quotes are exact:  `header='--header="..."'`

Answer (score 33):

You have to use double quotes when using the variable. Otherwise it will be expanded into multiple words. On the other hand, there is no need to quote the variable value twice. The following should work:

```
header='--header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'
wget "$header" http://website.com -O index
```

**Edit:** If you want to use variables for several arguments, use arrays:

```
args=(-d '--header=User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')
wget "${args[@]}" http://website.com -O index
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this

```
wget $header http://website.com -O index
```

try this,

```
wget "$header" http://website.com -O index
```

The spaces in the header text is breaking up when you are assigning it the header variable.
To do away with the problem you must surround a variable with quotes "".

**After comments:**
Try this -

```
someheader="-d --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'"
wget "$someheader" http://website.com -O index
```

The name header seems conflicting with your --header. Or, may be the quotes, instead of copying type them and retry. Still, Weird!

Comment: @rabotalius: what does echo "$header" emit as an output? Add that to your script before wget command and check.

Comment: `./test.sh
-d --header="User-Agent:\ Mozilla/5.0\ (Windows NT 6.0)\ AppleWebKit/537.11\ (KHTML, like Gecko)\ Chrome/23.0.1271.97\ Safari/537.11"
wget: invalid option -- ' '
wget: invalid option -- '-'
wget: invalid option -- '-'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.`

Comment: No first comment out the wget command like #wget ... and please provide the output of only echo "$header" command.

Comment: `-d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
`

Comment: Yup, now after echo "$header", place this - wget "$header" http://website.com -O index

Comment: Please use the command as I said, may be you are missing something.
I'm saying this because your echo "$header" seems fine to me.

Comment: @rabotalius: You quoted the header value twice, i.e. you have to remove the inner quotes. See also my answer.

Comment: @nosid not working... `header='-d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"';
wget "$header" http://google.com -O index        `

Comment: try with header="-d --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'";wget "$header" http://google.com -O index

Comment: @JtheRocker Doesn't work. Can you confirm it works on your system?

Comment: Ahh! what you have tried is this: header='-d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"'

Comment: Try this instead:

someheader="-d --header='User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11'"; wget "$someheader" google.com -O index

Comment: don't use header use someheader and check if it works. I guess somehow the name header is conflicting with your terminal. Weird!

Comment: @Whoever downvoted, please show some etiquette and tell why the downvote, please.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT: 'nosid's trick about the bash array worked for me. In my case the relevant code is:

```
WGET_OPTS="-r -N -nd -np -nH --timeout=120 --tries=3"
WGET_OPTS_ARRAY=(${WGET_OPTS// / })
wget "${WGET_OPTS_ARRAY[@]}" -A "$FILE_PAT" -P "$TO_DIR" "$FROM_URL"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you only need to do is to escape `-d` like this:

`header='\-d --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"'`

Answer (score 0):

the option "-d" show the header of yuor request and not have include in the header shell variable, like "-O index.html" option: for save the output into local file "index.html".
If you execute:

```
header='--header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"'
wget -d "$header" http://google.com -O index
```

it should work.